# Gönnen vs. vergönnen: what's the difference?

Tags: difference

In another question, someone asked about the verb gönnen. In the follow-up discussion the question arose as to whether the prefixes variant *vergönnen* has the same nuances? Ludi suggests they are quite different:

> I have been thinking about how to describe it. I will come back to you with
>   more battery and a clearer definition, but let me say for now, that
>   the meaning comes close to "allotted by God ", "granted by faith "...
>   It is often seen in the negative: "Ihr waren keine Kinder vergönnt",
>   "Eine solche Freude war ihnen nicht vergönnt"

I wonder if people would care to weigh in on this.

Comment: Einen nicht uninteressanten Artikel hierzu gab es [vor kurzem bei Dr. Bopp](http://canoo.net/blog/2015/04/30/vergoennen-war-nicht-immer-gleich-vergoennen/)

Answer (score 4):

In all my years I had only heard this word in reference to fate, God and similar entities. Typical usages would thus be similar to those of "beschieden":

> Es war mir nicht vergönnt sie wiederzusehen.
>
> Es war mir nicht beschieden sie wiederzusehen.

describing things granted or allotted by fate (usually, though, things denied).

Yet lexical definitions had made me suspect that - at least originally - the meaning was much closer to that of "gönnen". Somehow I never investigated it, but the comment about the Yiddish verb reignited my interest! I prefer old fashioned search to the Internet and hadn't found anything today. Before preparing for bed I found this dictionary: [Universal-Lexikon](http://universal_lexikon.deacademic.com/131944/verg%C3%B6nnen)
which lists examples for using "vergönnen" like "gönnen". I copy one:

> Dies war das einzige Vergnügen gewesen, das der Kellner Chwostik sich von Zeit zu Zeit vergönnt hatte *Doderer*, **Wasserfälle 30**.

I note that both authors cited by that reference are Austrian, although I suspect - from lexical definitions - that this use was not limited to Austria in the past.

I shall provide more examples of usage if I discover them!